# What is the InnoDB equivalent of MyISAM's key_buffer_size?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

When using MyISAM the configuration setting `key_buffer_size` defines the size of the global buffer where MySQL caches frequently used blocks of index data.

What is the corresponding setting for InnoDB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the setting that controls the size of the memory buffer that InnoDB uses to cache indexes *and* data.  It's an important performance option.

See the [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) for the full explanation.  The [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/) also has an article about how to choose a proper size for it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the best setting you can adjust for InnoDB is [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size).

> The size in bytes of the memory buffer
>   **InnoDB** uses to **cache** data and **indexes**
>   of its tables. The default value is
>   8MB. The larger you set this value,
>   the less disk I/O is needed to access
>   data in tables. On a dedicated
>   database server, you may set this to
>   up to 80% of the machine physical
>   memory size. However, do not set it
>   too large because competition for
>   physical memory might cause paging in
>   the operating system.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, because it's used to cache data as well as indexes, whereas MyISAM uses the OS's cache for data and its own key buffer for indexes.

Comment: I realize it's not the same but that's the closest InnoDB's got.