# Is key_buffer_size still applicable if all my tables are using InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

If I understand correctly in the documentation, `key_buffer_size` is only used for MyISAM tables. The documentation doesn't explicitly say that its not useful for other DB engines, though, hence the question.

Am I right in my assumption?

Comment: See: `innodb_buffer_pool_size `: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217825/what-is-the-innodb-equivalent-of-myisams-key-buffer-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, it is a MyISAM only parameter.

Having said that, note that the MySQL system tables are MyISAM. Consequently, I'd let it keep its default value (i.e. I'd never set it explicitly to zero).